# $window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Utilizo AngularJS em um webapp, neste webapp implantei um mapa onde mostra meus clientes a partir de um marcador. O mapa que estou utilizando é o Leaflet (http://leafletjs.com/) com uma diretiva para AngularJS (https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive).

Meu problema é o seguinte, quando acesso a primeira vez o mapa, funciona normalmente, quando altero a rota, ele apaga todos os marcadores, voltando a tela do mapa, ele carrega sem os marcadores e os mesmos são mostrados somente quando recarrego a página.

**Função $window.location.reload().**

Então, tive a ideia de utilizar o $window.location.reload() quando acessar a página onde encontra-se o mapa. Eu chamo a função quando clico no ícone de menu (atalho) da página referente o mapa e a página é recarregada mostrando os marcadores novamente.

```
vm.recarregarRota = function (){
        $window.location.reload();           
}
```

**View:** Este é o código que carrega o mapa.

```
<div class="col-md-12 box_map" style="padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;">
    <div id="recent_activity" class="box_whiteframe_map">
        <leaflet defaults="vm.defaults" lf-center="vm.center" ng-init="vm.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas()" markers="vm.markers" width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:** No controller encontra-se a função utilizada para carregar os dados do BD e atribuir aos marcadores. Também é nesta função que crio os marcadores, estender as propriedades do mapa, como dizer a ele que sua posição inicial é em tal coordenada..

Consideração sobre o controller.

a variável vm, recebe o $scope.

var vm = $scope.

```
        vm.markers = new Array(); //CRIA MARKERS A SEREM UTILIZADOS NO MAP

    vm.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas = function() { //Função utilizada para carregar os dados do BD e atribuir aos marcadores. Também é nesta função que crio os marcadores....
        vm.items = loadSaas(Cookies.get('crm_o2_hash')); // carregar saas id
        vm.items.then(function(items) { // ler array de retorno
            vm.saasid = items; //Armazena ID (saasid). 
            var dados = { 
                'saasid': vm.saasid
            }
            relatoriosService.carregarEnderecoClientesEmpresas(dados).then(function(response) {
                if (response.data != 'null') {
                    vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas = response.data; //ARRAY QUE VEM DO BD
                    angular.forEach(vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas, function(value, key) { //FOREACH UTILIZADO PARA PERCORRER ARRAY

                        vm.markers.push({
                            group: value.estado, //DADOS PROVENIENTES DO BD. 
                            lat: value.latitude, //DADOS PROVENIENTES DO BD. 
                            lng: value.longitude, //DADOS PROVENIENTES DO BD. 
                            message: "teste",
                            icon: {
                                type: 'awesomeMarker',
                                prefix: 'fa',
                                icon: icon,
                                markerColor: color
                            },
                            label: {
                                options: {
                                    noHide: true
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas = '';
                }

            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Erro findSemEmail: ', error);
            });
        });
    }


    angular.extend(vm, { // ESTENDE AS PROPRIEDADES DO MAP (MARCADORES, LOCALIZAÇÃO INCIAL..)
        center: { // LOCALIZAÇÃO INICIAL  .
            lat: -27.952419,
            lng: -52.211667,
            zoom: 6
        },
        defaults: { //LAYER É O TIPO DE MAPA A SER UTILIZADO
            tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            zoomControlPosition: 'topright',
            tileLayerOptions: {
                opacity: 0.9,
                detectRetina: true,
                reuseTiles: true,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | &copy <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">Funil PRÓ</a>',
            },
        }
    });
```

O meu problema é o seguinte, quando o usuário, ao invés de utilizar os atalhos do sistema par navegar, utilizar a seta de voltar do navegador, a página não irá recarregar, existe uma maneira de fazer com que a página recarregue se ele utilizar desta forma?

Ou talvez quando acessar uma rota específica recarregar a página.

PRINT'S DO CONSOLE:

Status inicial do mapa. Com todos os marcadores carregados percebe-se que o array foi percorrido 27 vezes (leafletDirective.layeradd).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem abaixo encontra-se o retorno do console de quando a rota muda. Veja que as layers (marcadores, tiles...) são removidos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por fim, nesta imagem uma layer (acredito que seja a tile (imagem de um mapa, no caso o OpenStreetMap) é carregada, mas não o restante das layers que seriam os marcadores (27)).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de muita investigação junto com o Fred no chat conseguimos concluir que isso é um bug da diretiva angular-leaflet-directive

O problema é descrito nesta issue:
https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/issues/381#issuecomment-46232650

Os clusters não são redesenhados porque o nome do grupo já está definido quando se retorna ao mapa

https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js#L2405

Para resolver isso é necessário resetar a variável *groups* da directiva com o *resetCurrentGroups* que está disponivel no leafletMarkersHelpers toda vez que se navega para fora do mapa, ou seja, toda vez que o $scope é destruído.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { 
    leafletMarkersHelpers.resetCurrentGroups(); 
});
```

Este helper **leafletMarkersHelpers** precisa ser injetado no controller antes de ser invocado

Comment: Link para o chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51887/discussion-between-fred-and-rodrigo-nishino 

Obrigado Rodrigo!

Answer (score 3):

Você está utilizando angular1?

Parece que o elemento está sendo inicializado pela primeira vez com ng-init e quando a rota muda o controller muda

Você considerou portar estes valores que estao sendo passados pelo ng-init para serem providos pelo controller relacionado pela rota?

```
$routeProvider.when("/mapa", {templateUrl : "main.htm", controller: "MapaCtrl"})

app.controller("MapaCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas = function(){ ... codigo aqui... }

    $scope.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas()

});
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder!

Sim, é o Angular1.
Quando você diz os valores, quer dizer os valores que são atribuídos aos markers? 
Como este por exemplo: lat: value.latitude, //DADOS PROVENIENTES DO BD.

Comment: vm.markers é um array vazio que é populado somentequando ng-init é invocado, só que ele esta sendo invocado somente no principio.

O ideal é chamar este metodo buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas no controller estabelecido na rota assim toda vez que a rota for apontada para o mapa de clientes o método é chamado e o array é atualizado

Comment: Quando eu troco a rota o método buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas é executado. Porém o array não é atualizado. Acabei criando uma função para criar o array vm.markers e executo essa função toda vez que o método é percorrido, porém, não funcionou.

Vou adicionar alguns prints do console na pergunta, talvez ajude.

Comment: Ahh, tentei executar a função no controller sim, até retirei o ng-init e deixei somente no controller, da forma que mostra no seu código acima. Porém carrega da mesma forma.

Comment: E esse  vm.items.then(function(items parece uma promise resolvida

Sera que perde a referencia?

Comment: Esse vm.items serve para carregar uma ID do usuários, para que só mostre informações deste usuário. Editei o código. Havia apagado prq não achei ser necessário, mas agora está editado.

Comment: Este vm.markers está no escopo do controller?
Não teria que ser $scope.vm.markers  ?

Comment: Ahh, esqueci de mencionar, a variável vm recebe o $scope. Então considere que em onde tem vm. é $scope.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51887/discussion-between-fred-and-rodrigo-nishino).